# In showing the principal branch of $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C\smallsetminus \mathbb{R}^{\leq 0}$, where is the branch used?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

Suppose we wanted to show that the principal branch - from here on denoted by $\operatorname{Log}(z)$- of the complex logarithm is holomorphic on its domain $\mathbb{C} \smallsetminus \mathbb{R}^{\leq 0}$.

Here is one approach, I believe.

> We have $\operatorname{Log}(z) = \log(|z|) + i \arg(z)$, where $\arg(z) \in (- \pi, \pi]$.
>
> It suffices to show that $L_{1}(x+iy)=\Re(\operatorname{Log}(z)) = \log(|z|) = \log(x^2 + y^2)$ and $L_2(x + iy)=\Im(\operatorname{Log}(z)) = \arg(z) = \arctan(\frac{y}{x})$ are $C^2$ functions  and that the respective partials $ \partial_{x} L_{1} $, $ \partial_{y} L_{1}$, $ \partial_{x} L_{2}$ and $\partial_{y} L_{2}$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.
>   Indeed,
>
> $ \partial_{x} L_{1} = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} = \partial_{y} L_{2}$ and $ \partial_{y} L_{1} =\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} = - \partial_{x} L_{2}$
>
> and the partials are clearly continuous. We conclude $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ is holomorphic on its domain.

Here is my question: Where did we use the specific properties of the branch. That is, it is clear to me that we have shown complex differentiability, but I don't see that we have shown this *specifically* for ***this*** branch of the complex logarithm.

Towards answering my own question: Is it that we are allowed to write $\arg(z) = \arctan( \frac{y}{x})$?

Comment: Yes exactely If $\arg(z)\in [\pi,3\pi)$, then $\arg(z)=\arctan(y/x)+2\pi$.

Comment: You dont use the properties of the particular branch, but if you dont do the branch cut then $\log$ is multivalued and in particular not analytic. So having a branch cut is a necessary condition for analyticity.

Comment: I see! "Complex differentiability" only makes sense for non-multi-functions?!

Comment: So this establishes that we have to use *a* branch. But where am I using the specific branch in my proof?

Comment: $\log$ will be analytic for any branch you pick. But for each branch the proof will be about a different branch cut. For example if you picked $(0, 2 \pi)$ as your branch, you could prove that $\log$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C} - [0, \infty)$, and with the branch you picked you proved its differentiability in $\mathbb{C}- (-\infty,0]$.

Comment: I understand. But where exactly does my argument make use of the restriction of the domain to $\mathbb{C} - (- \infty, 0]$? Thank you!

Comment: *edit to above comment : the domain should be $\mathbb{C} - [0, +\infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write $\arg z = \arctan (y/x)$, you have restricted $\arg z \in (-\pi, \pi)$, so you have chosen the branch to be $\mathbb{C} \smallsetminus \{z \in \mathbb{R} : z \leq 0\}$, i.e., discarding the points with argument $-\pi$.  (There's actually more to say here.  "$y/x$" passes through two periods of the tangent as $x+\mathrm{i}y$ wanders over the plane.  It would be better to write $\arctan(y,x)$, the [version of the arctangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Two-argument_variant_of_arctangent) that tracks which quadrant contains $x+\mathrm{i}y$.  But this version allows the angle $\pi$.  So what we want is a function like the normal arctangent which has an upper and lower horizontal asymptote, to chop out the non-positive real axis, and which spans from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.)

Notice that you could choose a different ray for the branch cut from $0$ by setting $\arg z = \theta + \arctan(y/x)$, which puts the branch cut at $-\pi + \theta$.  (One can even make the branch cut be a curve different from a ray by letting $\theta$ be a continuous function depending on the radius.  In general, all one needs from the cut to get holomorphicity is that the cut runs from $0$ to complex infinity and does not self-intersect.)

We also use the specific branch cut when we do *not* check the compatibility of the partial derivatives along $\{z \in \mathbb{R} : z \leq 0\}$, where such a check would fail.  In particular, the $\frac{\partial \ln(x+\mathrm{i}y)}{\partial y}$ derivative does not exist on the cut because the logarithm has a jump discontinuity as you cross the cut in the $y$-direction.  For instance, along the circle of radius $r$, \begin{align*}
\lim_{\theta \rightarrow \pi^-} \ln (r \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta}) &= \mathrm{i} \pi \ln r  \quad \text{ and }  \\
\lim_{\theta \rightarrow -\pi^+} \ln (r \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta}) &= -\mathrm{i} \pi \ln r \text{.}
\end{align*}